# Use sbt-projectmatrix to create AutoPlugin. How to set scalaVersion?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I use [sbt-projectmatrix](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-projectmatrix) to create 2 sbt plugins with customRow:

```scala
case class MatrixAxis(
  idSuffix: String,
  directorySuffix: String
) extends VirtualAxis.WeakAxis

// sbt
val oss = MatrixAxis("-oss", "oss")
val priv = MatrixAxis("-priv", "priv")
val scalaV = ???
lazy val devops = projectMatrix
  .enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)
  .settings(
    pluginCrossBuild / sbtVersion := "1.3.13", // minimum sbt version
  ).customRow(
    scalaVersions = Seq(scalaV),
    axisValues = Seq(priv, VirtualAxis.jvm),
    _.settings(...)
  .customRow(
    scalaVersions = Seq(scalaV),
    axisValues = Seq(oss, VirtualAxis.jvm),
    _.settings(...)
```

In [sbt's guide](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Creating+an+auto+plugin), they said:

> sbt plugins must be compiled with Scala 2.12.x that sbt itself is compiled in. By NOT specifying scalaVersion, sbt will default to the Scala version suited for a plugin.

But I don't know how to create a customRow without setting scalaVersions?

(If I set `scalaVersions = Nil` then projectMatrix will not create any project for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt-projectmatrix requires to know the Scala version statically, because, among other things, it uses it to build the ID of the project. So unfortunately, in the `scalaVersions` argument, we cannot read the value of `scalaVersion.value` to know what sbt would pick by default.

What we can do is to cheat a little: first, use any hard-coded 2.12.x version (e.g., 2.12.1) to write in `scalaVersions`. Then, explicitly override `scalaVersion := ...`, by-passing the 2.12.1 that sbt-projectmatrix would set:

```scala
val oss = MatrixAxis("-oss", "oss")
val priv = MatrixAxis("-priv", "priv")
val scalaV = "2.12.1" // arbitrary 2.12.x version
lazy val devops = projectMatrix
  .enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)
  .settings(
    pluginCrossBuild / sbtVersion := "1.3.13", // minimum sbt version
    /* override with the default scalaVersion in the Global scope,
     * which is sbt's choice, not impacted by sbt-projectmatrix
     */
    scalaVersion := (Global / scalaVersion).value,
  ).customRow(
    scalaVersions = Seq(scalaV),
    axisValues = Seq(priv, VirtualAxis.jvm),
    _.settings()
  )
  .customRow(
    scalaVersions = Seq(scalaV),
    axisValues = Seq(oss, VirtualAxis.jvm),
    _.settings()
  )
```